# Puppet Master Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter path at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

Tags: puppet

How do I pass file name as arguments to puppet class?
My manifest file is

```
class new_file ($my_filename){
    file { $my_filename:
        ensure => present,
        content => "I got it, Hello, I am Aura, with new content\n",
    }
}

node 'agent1' {
  class {new_file: path => "/tmp/t.txt", }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class accepts a parameter called `my_filename`:

> class new_file ($my_filename){

But here you're supplying `path`:

> class {new_file: path => "/tmp/t.txt", }

Change this parameter to the same name and it will prevent the `invalid parameter path` error:

```
class {new_file: my_filename => "/tmp/t.txt", }
```